# Gzipped response in AWS Lambda -> API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, gzip, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I can't seem to get a gzipped response from Lambda through the API Gateway.
I'm gzipping my response in Lambda and setting the "Content-Encoding" header in API Gateway.

I'm not sure which part is the problem.

Here's the final return from Lambda to API Gateway:

```
zlib.gzip(myJsonString, function (err, buffer) {
    if ( err ) { return handleError(err, context) }

    return context.succeed(buffer.toString('binary'));
});
```

I've tried just passing the buffer, base64 encoding it, etc.

Making a GET request from Chrome:
If I remove the Content-Encoding header from the gateway I get binary/base64/buffer array as a string response in the browser.

If I set the header, the GET request fails entirely with no response but testing in the AWS console returns the payload with quotes around it.

I don't know what's going on here but If Amazon actually wants people to use this thing we need to be able to compress our responses. Seems like it should just be a checkbox in API Gateway and then I could simply return a JSON string from Lambda and have it zipped up automatically.

Comment: I have the same issue and this is disappointing to say the least :/ Why isn't everyone using APIG for a REST API complaining about this? :)

Answer (score 2):

As for Nov 17, 2016 - [Binary Data Now Supported by API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/)

Let me know if you figured that out!

Comment: Any news regarding this matter?

Comment: @PedroBaptistaAfonso check out this example of how to use gzip
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/pull/51